# Does not display data after filling in the template

Tags: python, html, django

I make comments on the site and cannot understand why, after the user has filled out comment forms, they are not displayed, I try to display them through a template
P.S

I need to display the text and the nickname that the user would enter

views.py

```
def CommentGet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = Comments(request.POST)

        name = request.POST['name']
        text = request.POST['text']


        if comment.is_valid():

            comment.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)


        comments = CommentModel.objects.all()

    else:
        comment = Comments(request.POST)

        comments = CommentModel.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'news/post.html', {'comment': comment,'comments':comments})
```

post.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'comment' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ name }}">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="{{ text }}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

{% for comm in comments %}

<h1> {{ comm.name }} </h1>
<h1> {{ comm.text }} </h1>

{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class CommentModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    dates = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dates']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a `ModelForm` to make things simpler, Try something like this:

```
# views.py
def CommentGet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        comment_form.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    comments = CommentModel.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'news/post.html', {'comment_form': comment_form,'comments':comments, })
```

```
# forms.py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CommentModel
        fields = ['name', 'text']
```

Then, in your template, replace the two text fields with `{{ comment_form }}`